# How to move h file in Visual Studio project to a new folder

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I have C++ project in Visual Studio 2017. 
Number of headers has grown a bit and I want to organize them into folders(like instead all files living in project folder I want them to live in separate subfolders, like util, engine, ai ...)

It is unclear to me from UI how it can be done beside crude deletion and manual addition of "new" header that is then filled with content of the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on 'Header Files'.
Then under 'Add' you can add folders to filter into and add existing files into them.

You can also create those folders and manually move the 'files' into the folders in 'file explorer'.